# this.setState with not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set state and then call another function with the current state just after setting it.

**I have this kind of code**

```
this.setState({
      candidates : diCandi
    },()=>{
      this.createDataSource(this.state)
      console.log("The state is=>",this.state);
    });
```

I want to call `this.createDataSource(this.state)` with the state i just updated.
Its  not working I wonder why. Is there anything i am doing wrong

Infact when i log out the state. I never see the code in the logs.

Comment: _not working_ is not enough of information. Please give more context to your problem. If you are getting any errors or odd behavior please add it to your question.

Comment: That should work, the point of the callback is it's not triggered until the state is updated (as that may be asynchronous). Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: clarify what is `not working`. You can try to log from within `createDataSource` and see if the state is new(which it should be). So you need to findout what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { candidates: "no candidates" }
  }
  
  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    return false;
  }
  
  buttonClick(e){
    this.setState({candidates: "diCandi"}, () => console.log("updated"))
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}>set candidates</button>
        <b>{this.state.candidates}</b>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('container')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, MOUNT_NODE)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
```

The code should work as mentioned earlier by Sagar, the callback on this.setState() only kicks in after the state has been set. The callback works even if shouldComponentUpdate is returning false

Answer (score 0):

you send all the state to `createDataSource` you can do

```
this.setState({
  candidates : diCandi
},()=>{
  this.createDataSource(this.state.candidates) 
  console.log("The state is=>",this.state.candidates);
});
```

also it is recommended to access the state from `createDataSource` method not sending it as params

```
this.setState({
  candidates : diCandi
},()=>{
  this.createDataSource() 
  console.log("The state is=>",this.state.candidates);
});
```

then in `createDataSource`

```
createDataSource() {
  this.state.candidates
  .... rest of code
}
```